# Questions about chmod options

Tags: chmod

I would like to know the purpose of the command below :

**find /toto/titi -type d -exec sudo chmod 2755 {} \;**

Especially what's after 2755 because I can't seem to find what it does ?

Thanx in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be posted to the unix stackexchange site.

Answer (score 1):

- `find /toto/titi` - find files recursively starting in `/toto/titi`
- `-type d` - only find directories
- `-exec sudo chmod 2755 {} \;` - for each file that you find, run the command `sudo chmod 2755 <file>;`.  `{}` stands for the name of the file that was found, and `\;` is needed to end the `-exec` statement.